# Need Help using Join and Select statement in Where Clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql, left-join, where-clause, moodle

Need Help in this SQL

```
SELECT mdl_course_completions.course, mdl_course.fullname, mdl_course_completions.userid, mdl_user_enrolments.userid, mdl_user_enrolments.enrolid 
FROM mdl_course_completions 
LEFT JOIN mdl_course ON mdl_course_completions.course = mdl_course.id 
LEFT JOIN mdl_user_enrolments ON mdl_course_completions.userid = mdl_user_enrolments.userid 
WHERE mdl_user_enrolments.enrolid IN
      (SELECT mdl_enrol.id from mdl_enrol where mdl_enrol.courseid = mdl_course_completions.course)
```

In mdl_course_completions table, We have 3122 records of which 1471 are relevant records in mdl_user_enrolment. For the balance 3122-1471 (1651), it should still extract the data for mdl_course_completions.course, mdl_course.fullname & mdl_course_completions.userid with blank fields under mdl_user_enrolments.userid, mdl_user_enrolments.enrolid

This system does not have proper Foreign Keys defined, hence the usage of Relationship is not maintained similarly across tables, hence to get the records from mdl_user_enrolment need to have the select clause.

Can someone help with a solution. Appreciate the same.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean by *This system is not defined as a proper RDBMS as it is a opensource,*.

Comment: 'This system is not defined as a proper RDBMS as it is a opensource'  - so what as long as these your tables exist in a DB you can join them if there are relationships between them - it doesn't matter if no indexes or FKs exist (expect for performance). Your query looks like it might work BTW - if not what problem are you having.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

When you mentioned a column from a LEFT JOINed table in a WHERE clause, you converted the LEFT JOIN to an ordinary inner JOIN, and so suppressed the rows that don't match the `ON` clause from your result set.

```
  ...
  LEFT JOIN mdl_user_enrolments
            ON mdl_course_completions.userid = mdl_user_enrolments.userid 
 WHERE mdl_user_enrolments.enrolid IN
         (SELECT mdl_enrol.id 
            from mdl_enrol
           where mdl_enrol.courseid = mdl_course_completions.course)
```

Try refactoring the WHERE as another LEFT JOIN like this

```
  ...
  LEFT JOIN mdl_user_enrolments
            ON mdl_course_completions.userid = mdl_user_enrolments.userid 
  LEFT JOIN md_enrol 
            ON md_enrol.courseid = mdl_course_completions.course
```

and see if you get the correct result set.

And, with respect, try telling the MySQL, MariaDB, and PostgreSQL open source development teams that their products aren't proper RDBMSs. I suspect they will disagree.

Comment: Sorry I did not mean  MySQL being a RDBMS or not, in fact what I meant was the Application did not use Foreign Key because of which the usage of Joins had to deal with multiple tables.

Comment: Thank you all, Based on Philips answer added an AND clause to the Left Join and it worked.